How to get stream response from open ai in next js 13 app
I want to get valid response in form of stream from open ai in to my next js version 13 app and render it on the screen
Here is what I did in my sendMessage.js
export default async function handler(req) {
  try {
    const { message } = await req.json();
    const stream = await OpenAIEdgeStream(
      "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions",
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY}`,
          "content-type": "application/json",
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
          message: [{ content: message, role: "user" }],
          stream: true,
        }),
      }
    );

    return new Response(stream);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in API:", error.message);
  }
}

And below is the page where it calls the above handler function
try {
const res = await fetch("/api/chat/sendMessage", {
method: "POST",
headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
body: JSON.stringify({
message: messageText,
}),
});

      const data = await res.body;
      const reader = data.getReader();
      await streamReader(reader, async (message) => {
        console.log(message);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error.message);
    }

I was expecting to get a response from open ai but I didn't I'm not getting any errors but it's also not returning any response
